# What determines object size here?

Tags: c++, sizeof

I have created simple object containing integer and few methods, integer primitive variable alone and compare their sizes. "sizeof()" for both returned value of "4". Why is that - shouldn't object that is composite type and contains information about methods take more space?

```
#include <iostream>

class Person{

    private:
        int a;

    public:

        void hello(){
            std::cout << "hello";
        }

        void DoSomething(){
            a++;
        }
};

int main(){

    int a;
    Person p;

    std::cout << sizeof(a) << std::endl;

    std::cout << sizeof(p) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: methods are not part of object only members

Comment: Add the keyword `virtual` to your declaration of `hello()` and run the program again. You'll note that it no longer prints 4 twice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The methods (technically *member functions* in C++ terminology) do not contribute to the "size" of an object. If you think about it, it makes sense. A member function is applicable to **any** object instantiated from the class or its descendants, and is in a sense independent of the instance. You can think of the member function of some fictive class `Foo` as being a standalone function declared as

```
return_type some_member_function(Foo* ptr, /* other params */){...}
```

where the first parameter is a pointer to the instance you are applying the function to. The compiler actually passes the pointer `ptr` implicitly when calling the member function, so

```
foo.some_member_function(/* other params */)
```

is being translated internally as

```
some_member_function(&foo, /* other params */)
```

You can use the address of the current instance pointed by `ptr` in actual C++ code via the keyword `this`. Technically [the keyword `this` is a prvalue expression whose value is the address of the object, on which the member function is being called.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this)

---

PS: as @greyfade mentioned in the comment, the size of an object may be increased by a mere declaration of `virtual` member function(s), since in this case the compiler must store internally a pointer to the so called "virtual table". This is the case no matter if the virtual function is being overridden or not. So, if you care about object size, don't blindly make the destructor virtual, unless you plan to use your class as the base in a hierarchy.

Comment: Not quite *any* object, but objects of that type (or subclasses). Overridden virtual functions make things a bit more complicated.

Comment: `virtual` functions don't even need to be overridden to have an effect. Their mere existence imposes a vtable pointer.

Comment: @greyfade yes, that makes the size of the object larger, due to the pointer-to-vtable, but I guess the OP was thinking about the non-virtual case.

Comment: @vsoftco: It's worth discussing in any event: member functions *can* have an effect on the class size, but only in a specific circumstance.

Comment: It might make sense for expositional purposes to name "ptr" "this" instead.

Comment: @BenPope, makes sense, but didn't want to use it since `this` is a C++ keyword referring to a prvalue expression whose value is the address of the object. But yes, one can use `this` inside the member function to refer exactly to what I called `ptr`, I updated my answer.

Comment: Another factor is that the vtable can be optimized out if the compiler determines it's not necessary.  (I think gcc and clang will do this at link stage, but neither chooses to go so far as to not even include the vtable pointer in the class)

Comment: For overload resolution it behaves as if there were a hidden first parameter `Foo&` , and it's matched using `*this`

Comment: @MattMcNabb correct, I used the pointer example since references may also be implemented via pointers by the compiler. But technically you're right, the call is being made via a reference to `*this`. I guess the vtable can be optimized out if you have no overridden functions, although in that case I cannot see why the pointer itself cannot be simply "optimized out".

Comment: @MattMcNabb the exception may be the declaration of a virtual destructor, which is automatically propagated to the derived classes. But if the destructor is not declared virtual, and no other base functions are overridden, then imo the pointer should be removed by the compiler.

Comment: I guess people would complain if their class size jumps around depending on the optimization flags passed to compiler.  Although I know one library that has a larger `vector` in debug mode than release mode.